# Agora.io Sending Image and pdf while doing text chatting

Tags: android, image, pdf, agora.io

With the given code samples we have tried to text chatting and it is working. We want to use documents sharing in the same chat window and I don't see any code samples for the same. Not sure whether this feature is available in Agora.io. Did anyone tried using Agora.io chat feature with documents sharing such as pdf, images etc. I want similar functionality of whatsapp. Any references would be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

Agora RTM Docs: https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/product_rtm?platform=All%20Platforms

Agora RTM's maximum message size is 32 KB and it can be a text message or a text description of the raw message or JSON.

Agora itself does not provide any APIs to share files.

What you can actually do is, let's say if you UserA wants to share an image to UserB. UserA first uploads the image to your own server or an S3 bucket once done get the uploaded link and share the link with the description and type as an image in JSON format to UserB through Agora RTM p2p message and when UserB receives the message render it directly as image.

**sendMessageToPeer**: https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/API%20Reference/RTM_java/classio_1_1agora_1_1rtm_1_1_rtm_client.html#a729079805644b3307297fb2e902ab4c9